# The beginning of the response from api GPT is eaten during an asynchronous request

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, aiogram, chatgpt-api

I am writing a bot through aiogram and attached gpt to it, but with asynchronous requests, the beginning of the text began to eat up. Such a thing is only with an asynchronous request, through the Openai module. I also tried using aiohttp and it turned out to get rid of this problem by turning off the stream, but I would certainly like to leave the opportunity to receive not 1 final answer with a fully prepared text, but many small ones in parts. I would be grateful for any hints. I will attach the code of the function in which the request to the api is made below ...And by the way. It does not always eat the beginning of the text. Periodically.

```
async def send_message_gpt(prompt, id, anounce):
    main_menu_keyboard = 
    types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(types.KeyboardButton("Main menu"))
    result = ""
    await bot.send_message(id, "<b>Text processing in progress!</b>", parse_mode='html', reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard)
    generate_text = await bot.send_message(id, "...", parse_mode='html')


  response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613', messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": f"{prompt}"}], stream=True)

  symbol_step = 100

  for message in response:
      try:
        result += message["choices"][0]["delta"]["content"]
        if len(result) >= symbol_step:
            await generate_text.edit_text(result)
            symbol_step += 100
    except:
        pass

  if anounce:
    new_gen_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(types.KeyboardButton("Regenerate text"), types.KeyboardButton("Main menu")).add(types.KeyboardButton("Generate Title and Announcement"))
  else:
    new_gen_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(
        types.KeyboardButton("Regenerate text"), types.KeyboardButton("Main menu"))

  await generate_text.edit_text(result)
  await bot.send_message(id, f'Text generated!', reply_markup=new_gen_keyboard)
  await ProfilesStatesGroup.new_gen.set()

  return result
```

I tried the aiohttp library. I also tried to make a request asynchronously:
response = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(model='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613', messages=[
{"role": "user", "content": f"{prompt}"}], stream=True)